SonarQube quality gate passes on first scan despite expected failure
I am currently using SonarQube in the Jenkins pipeline for continuous code quality checks. However, I have noticed an issue where the SonarQube Quality Gate passes on the first scan even when it should have failed.
This behavior is inconsistent with subsequent scans, which seem to correctly fail the Quality Gate when the conditions are not met. I am looking for insights into why this might be happening and how I can ensure that the Quality Gate correctly fails on the first scan when the conditions are not met.
I have tried running the Jenkins pipeline with SonarQube multiple times. I have also checked the configuration of the Quality Gate in SonarQube and it seems to be set up correctly. I have also tried looking into the logs of both Jenkins and SonarQube to identify any potential issues, but I couldn’t find anything that would explain this behavior.
I was expecting the SonarQube Quality Gate to fail on the first scan if the conditions are not met, similar to how it behaves in subsequent scans. I am not sure why this is not the case and I am looking for any potential reasons that could explain this behavior.
